# How to check how many times a variable has held the same value

Tags: python, count

For example let's say

```
my_variable = int(input("Choose a number"))
```

If I then keep changing the variable, is there a way that I can count how many times "my_variable" has had the same value?

Comment: I'd suggest you look into using a Counter object to keep track of the count.. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It's called design your own algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't provide a way to track changes on a global variables, so I would put this in a loop and keep a list of all previous values the variable has taken, like this:

```
values = []
while True:
    my_variable = int(input("Choose a number"))
    values.append(my_variable)
```

Obviously, you'll need to add some condition for it to know when to break out of the loop, but you can now easily count how many times a particular value has shown up in the `values` list.  As other answers have said, using a Counter would be a good idea for this.  If you want to go straight to the Counter instead of having to call `Counter(list)` every time you want to get counts, you can do:

```
from collections import Counter
values = Counter()
while True:
    my_variable = int(input("Choose a number"))
    values[my_variable] += 1
```

Here's an example of a program where it keeps prompting the user for numbers until some number has been entered 3 times:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
while True:
    my_variable = int(input("Choose a number"))
    counts[my_variable] += 1
    num, count = counts.most_common(1)[0]
    if count == 3:
        break
# Figure out what number was input 3 times:
num, count = counts.most_common(1)[0]
print(num)
```

[See here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for the docs about collections.Counter, including an explanation of the `Counter.most_common` method

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program many times, the only way is to make the program write down what your input was to a file. If this goes on in a loop it's easier, just create a list to which you append `my_variable` and call `collections.Counter` on that list.

Comment: I only need it in a loop. So I would do list = [(my_variable)] and then do collections.counter(list)? What would this return if, say, my_variable had been equal to 3, 8 times?

Comment: You should do `listname = []` and each time after `my_variable` changes do `listname.append(my_variable)`, then `collections.Counter(listname)` gets you a dictionary saying, in your example: `{3: 8}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to count previous values of a simple variable. But it is possible to create a property that keeps track of assignation and count them.

```
from collections import Counter

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_values = Counter()
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self.x_values[x] += 1


c = MyClass()
c.x = 1
c.x = 2
c.x = 3
c.x = 3
c.x = 2
c.x = 1
c.x = 1

print(c.x_values)
# prints Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2})
```